# Java regex to remove all the characters after space in the end tag of an xml

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have an XML file in the following format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SampleData ID="Test" Password="Test">
<STATUS operation=”remove”>EXPIRED</STATUS operation=”remove”>
<PRIVILEGE operation=”remove”>12345</PRIVILEGE operation=”remove”>
<userID>ABC123</userID>
<PROFILE operation=”remove”>DEFAULT</PROFILE operation=”remove”>
</SampleData>
```

Here in this XML, I don't want any text in the end tag after space. For example, if you consider the end tag `</STATUS operation=”remove”>`, I just want it to show like `</STATUS>`. If there is no space in any of the end tags then that tag can remain the same. Also, the start tags will remain the same in any case.

Can someone please suggest me any regex where I can parse through the whole XML and check for each end tag so that I can get rid of any characters after space in those tags.

Comment: What a strange XML, I have never seen attributes in closing tags.

Comment: Please don't call it XML when it isn't. The best way of handling stuff that purports to be XML but isn't, is to fix the bug in the program that created it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do accomplish this:

```
final String regex = "(<\\/.*)\\ (.*)>";

final String string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
         + "<SampleData ID=\"Test\" Password=\"Test\">\n"
         + "<STATUS operation=”remove”>EXPIRED</STATUS operation=”remove”>\n"
         + "<PRIVILEGE operation=”remove”>12345</PRIVILEGE operation=”remove”>\n"
         + "<userID>ABC123</userID>\n"
         + "<PROFILE operation=”remove”>DEFAULT</PROFILE operation=”remove”>\n"
         + "</SampleData>";

final String subst = "$1>";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println(result);
```

**Outputs**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SampleData ID="Test" Password="Test">
<STATUS operation=”remove”>EXPIRED</STATUS>
<PRIVILEGE operation=”remove”>12345</PRIVILEGE>
<userID>ABC123</userID>
<PROFILE operation=”remove”>DEFAULT</PROFILE>
</SampleData>
```

**Test it here: [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/ux8BBa/1)**